# How to fix preventDefault error in OceanWP main.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome, events, preventdefault

I am ussing OceanWP on my wordpress site and have preventDefault issue after Chrome update.

**[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See**

Tried adding { passive: false } in all places where I had preventDefault

Scrolling is very glitchy due to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

turn off smooth scroll.

Admin area > theme panel > smoothscroll switch off

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue in my Wordpress website (Only chrome).

I added this [MouseWheel Smooth Scroll By KubiQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mousewheel-smooth-scroll/) plugin in my website. And now scroll issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I used Chases method and it worked just fine and was super simple!

Comment: Okay. That's great..!!